# Can this destroy my entire website?

Tags: git, bash

I have the following post-commit hook for git:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Save this in: /home/qwertymk/website-live.git/hooks/post-receive

# let's save all of out js files before the checkout
FILES="$(find /home/qwertymk/public_html -type f -name '*.js')"
for f in $FILES
do
 if [[ $f =~ /home/qwertymk/ignore-dir/dev-staging-area/ ]]; then continue; fi
  echo "copying - $f"
  cp $f $f.jscache
done
# done saving js files before checkout

export GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/qwertymk/public_html/
git checkout -f

# minify each js file that changed
cd /home/qwertymk/website-live.git
FILES=$(git whatchanged -n 1 --pretty=format: --name-only | grep '\.js$')
for f in $FILES
do
  echo "processing - $f"
  rm /home/qwertymk/public_html/$f.jscache
  php /home/qwertymk/jsmin/curl.php /home/qwertymk/public_html/$f
done
# done minifing

# anything that has a .jscache should be moved to the .js
FILES="$(find /home/qwertymk/public_html -type f -name '*.js')"
for f in $FILES
do
 if [[ $f =~ /home/qwertymk/public_html/dev-staging-area/ ]]; then continue; fi
 if [ ! -f $f.jscache ]; then continue; fi
  echo "restoring - $f"
  rm $f
  mv $f.jscache $f
done
```

Is there anything wrong with this script?

Can I feel safe in using it?

Are there any corner cases where this script can mess up my site?

Comment: is there something in particular that worries you?

Comment: @abresas: The fact that I may delete all myjs files by accident

Comment: look at other posts that use `find ... | while read filename  ; do ` postings here on S.O. It gets mentioned just about everyday. Using `FILES=$(find ...)` will break when you have spaces or other odd chars in a filename, either by design or accident. It also helps to turn `rm $f` into `printf -- rm $f "\n"`, etc. so you can see what commands will be executed. When you're satisfied the output is safe, then redirect whole script output into a shell. i.e. `myGitThing | bash`. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at other posts that use

```
find ... -print0 | xargs ??? | while read filename ; do ...
```

postings here on S.O. It gets mentioned just about everyday. If your version of `find` support the `-print0` option (indicating null terminated string output), then you're all set. You need to find the corresponding argument for xargs to indicate you're sending in null terminated strings.

Using `FILES=$(find ...)` will break when you have spaces or other odd chars in a filename, either by design or accident, so that's why you want to use `-print0` if you can.

To really be safe, turn all destructive code like `rm $f` into `printf -- rm $f "\n"`, etc. so you can see what commands will be executed BEFORE you execute them.

When you're satisfied the output is safe, then redirect whole script output into a shell. i.e.

```
myGitThing | bash
```

Answer (score 1):

My own take on [looping over `find` results](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/master/examples/safe-find.sh) ([featured](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1343/can-you-break-this-code) on Code Review), which is safe enough to handle *any* characters you can put in a path (its equivalent is used on production servers to move and delete critical files):

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' -u 9
do
    file_path="$(readlink -fn -- "$REPLY"; echo x)"
    file_path="${file_path%x}"
    echo "START${file_path}END" # Literal
    printf %q "$file_path" # Bash escaped
done 9< <( find /home/qwertymk/public_html -type f -name '*.js' -print0 )
```

Please see the link for an explanation of all the weird syntax.